# запрашиваются значения там, где не должны этого делать

Tags: python-3.x

Небольшой блок кода:

```
   class Restaurant():

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
      print(self.restaurant_name.title())
      print(self.cuisine_type.title())

    def open_restaurant(self, restaurant_name):
        print(self.restaurant_name.title() + ' now open !')



restaurant = Restaurant('food farm', 'european')

print(restaurant.restaurant_name.title())
print(restaurant.cuisine_type.title())

restaurant.describe_restaurant()      <------ ЗДЕСЬ
restaurant.open_restaurant()            <------ И ЗДЕСЬ
```

При вызове методов restaurant.describe_restaurant() и restaurant.open_restaurant(), пишет мне:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restaurant.py", line 22, in <module>
    restaurant.describe_restaurant()
TypeError: describe_restaurant() missing 2 required positional arguments: 
'restaurant_name' and 'cuisine_type'




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restaurant.py", line 23, in <module>
    restaurant.open_restaurant()
TypeError: open_restaurant() missing 1 required positional argument: 
'restaurant_name'
```

Нашел небольшой способ исправить это - достаточно в вызове метода написать пустые аргументы: 
пример -->     restaurant.describe_restaurant('','')
  со вторым методом аналогично.

ОЧЕНЬ надеюсь, что есть более серьезный метод исправить это.

Comment: `def describe_restaurant(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type)` --> `def describe_restaurant(self)`

Comment: если вы не используете параметры в функции значит они лишние. `self.restaurant_name` - это переменная класса, а `restaurant_name` - параметр - они не имеют ничего общего